# QtSql cannot execute a query

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, qtsql

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName("test");
    db.setDatabaseName("firma");
    db.setUserName("user");
    db.setPassword("pass");

    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << db.lastError();
        return 1;
    }

    QSqlQuery query;
    bool ret = query.exec("CREATE TABLE employees(id int primary key auto_increment, lastname varchar(255), firstname varchar(255), department int) ");
    qDebug() << ret << endl;
}
```

Every time I get **false**. I can't get the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite prefers to see [`autoincrement`](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint) and only wants to apply it to `integer` columns, `auto_increment` is a syntax error with SQLite. Your SQL should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(id integer primary key autoincrement, ...
```

Comment: I managed it with a cut of **CHARSET** and **auto_incremnt**. Btw, **autoincrement** also not working.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE employees(id int primary key auto_increment, lastname varchar(255), firstname varchar(255), department int)` gives me a syntax error in the `sqlite3` CLI tool, changing it as above makes it work fine. I also changed `int` to `integer`.

Answer (score 1):

QSqlQuery can help you find out why exec() returns false. Call [QSqlError QSqlQuery::lastError () const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#lastError), then [QString QSqlError::text () const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlerror.html#text). What you get is the text of the error as reported by the database and the driver.